# Clone not invoked for Moved value?

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand how Copy interacts with move semantics in Rust. I expected this program to clone the object, but it does not. I have rust 1.0.0-beta.

```
#[derive(Debug)]                                  
struct X {
  y : i32,
}

impl Clone for X {
  fn clone(&self) -> X { 
    println!("clone");
    X { y: 4 }
  } 
}

impl Copy for X { }  

fn doit(x : X) {     
  println!("doit {:?}", x);
}

fn main() { 
  let z = X { y: 5 };    
  println!("main {:?}", z);
  doit(z);        
  println!("main {:?}", z);
}
```

Here's my confusion: If X were not "Copy", doit would take ownership of the object z and drop it at the end of scope. Then, the second println in main would complain because z was moved. Fine. However, now I've marked X as Copy and provided a clone method. I expected the clone method would be used to provide doit with its own copy of z, thus allowing me to continue using z after doit. That doesn't happen.

Where is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Clone` is nothing special. It's just an ordinary library trait. You could define it yourself!

Consequently, `.clone()` is only used when you explicitly call it. Neither copying nor moving has anything to do with `Clone`. When you call `doit(z)`, `z` is copied in the `Copy` sense, which means a byte-wise copy under the hood. If you want to clone to pass it to `doit`, then write that:

```
doit(z.clone());
```

Comment: What is the point of Copy requiring Clone if it goes behind my back with memcpy anyway? I somehow expected this to behave more like a C++ copy constructor.

Comment: @WesleyW.Terpstra Copy requires Clone to prevent a common oversight (implementing Copy but not Clone, which breaks interoperability with APIs that use `Clone`). Rust has nothing like C++ copy constructors, which has many advantages and a couple of disadvantages.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I just find it jarring that clone and copy can behave differently.

Comment: @terpstra Look at it like this: `Clone` is a general property you can give a type.  It says "it's possible, with some work, to make a copy of values of this type".  If it's logically valid, you can pretty much *always* implement `Clone`.  `Copy` is more specialised; it says "you can create a copy by ignoring `Clone::clone` and just `memcpy`-ing the bytes", but requires that this actually make a valid copy (which is not always true).

Answer (score 2):

The [current (2021) documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Copy.html#whats-the-difference-between-copy-and-clone) is now clearer

> ### What's the difference between Copy and Clone?
>
> Copies happen implicitly, for example as part of an assignment `y = x`. The behavior of `Copy` is not overloadable; it is always a simple bit-wise copy.
>
> Cloning is an explicit action, `x.clone()`. The implementation of Clone can provide any type-specific behavior necessary to duplicate values safely.
> For example, the implementation of `Clone` for `String` needs to copy the pointed-to string buffer in the heap.
> A simple bitwise copy of String values would merely copy the pointer, leading to a double free down the line. For this reason, String is Clone but not Copy.
>
> `Clone` is a supertrait of `Copy`, so everything which is Copy must also implement `Clone`.
> If a type is `Copy` then its `Clone` implementation only needs to return `*self`

```rust
struct MyStruct;

impl Copy for MyStruct { }

impl Clone for MyStruct {
    fn clone(&self) -> MyStruct {
        *self
    }
}
```

See also the 2020 article "[Moves, copies and clones in Rust](https://hashrust.com/blog/moves-copies-and-clones-in-rust/) "

> When a value is moved, Rust does a shallow copy; but what if you want to create a deep copy like in C++?
> To allow that, a type must first implement the `Clone` trait.
> Then to make a deep copy, client code should call the `clone` method:
>
> ```rust
> let v: Vec<i32> = Vec::new();
> let v1 = v.clone();//ok since Vec implements Clone
> println!("v's length is {}", v.len());//ok
> ```
>
> This results in the following memory layout after the clone call:
> [image: https://hashrust.com/blog/moves-copies-and-clones-in-rust/vector-layout-cloned.svg]
> Due to deep copying, both `v` and `v1` are free to independently drop their heap buffers.
>
> ### Note
>
> The `clone` method doesn't always create a deep copy.
>
> Types are free to implement clone any way they want, but semantically it should be close enough to the meaning of duplicating an object.
> For example, [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html) increment a reference count instead.